# Authorized user condition that opens another DialogFragment

Tags: java, android

Made registration using `Firebase`. I need that when clicking on the same `CardView` different `DialogFragment` opens and the condition is whether the user is logged in or not, i.e. by clicking on the `CardView`, `DialogFragment1` opens in which the user logs in, if everything is successful `DialogFragment1` is closed and when the `CardView` is pressed again, DialogFragment2 is opened, how to do this?

My dialog through which the user logs in

```
public class FragmentDialogLogin extends Fragment {

    public static CardView close_dl, login_LG;
    public static boolean isRememberUserLogin;
    CardView registration;
    public static EditText User_Name_LG;
    public static EditText User_Password_LG;

    public static String name;
    public static String surname;
    public static String email;

    FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;
    DatabaseReference databaseReference;


    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public static LinearLayout Ll_LG;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog_login, container, false);
    }

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("Users");

        close_dl = view.findViewById(R.id.close_dl);
        close_dl.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            closeDialog();
        });

        registration = view.findViewById(R.id.registration);
        registration.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            int current = DialogAuthorization.VP_dialog_authorization.getCurrentItem();
            int totalItems = DialogAuthorization.VP_dialog_authorization.getAdapter().getCount();
            if (current < totalItems - 1) {
                DialogAuthorization.VP_dialog_authorization.setCurrentItem(current + 1, true);
            }
        });

        User_Name_LG = view.findViewById(R.id.User_Name_LG);
        User_Password_LG = view.findViewById(R.id.User_Password_LG);

        login_LG = view.findViewById(R.id.login_LG);
        login_LG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String email = User_Name_LG.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = User_Password_LG.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    User_Name_LG.setError("Email is Required.");
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    User_Password_LG.setError(getText(R.string.Rink));
                    return;
                }

                if (password.length() < 6) {
                    User_Password_LG.setError("Password Must be >= 6 Characters");
                    return;
                }

                firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Logged in Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            DialogProfile dialog = new DialogProfile();
                            dialog.show(requireFragmentManager(), "DialogProfile");
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error ! " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }

    private void closeDialog() {
        Fragment prev = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("DialogAuthorization");
        if (prev != null) {
            DialogAuthorization df = (DialogAuthorization) prev;
            df.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you using Firebase autentication, a web service, a local database or how do you know if ihe user has logged in or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to check whether user logged in or not is to call [getCurrentUser();](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user)

```
private DatabaseReference rootReference;
    private DatabaseReference usersRef;
    
    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
        @Override
        public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            ...
            
            rootReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); 
            usersRef = rootReference.child("Users");
            
            ...
            
            login_LG.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                
                ...
                
                // User already logged in
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                // Todo: close dialog fragment 1 and open dialog fragment 2
                return;
            }

            // user did not log in
            firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            
                                // Store that user logged in with email
                                String currentUserId = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                                rootReference.child("Users").child(currentUserId).setValue("email");
                            
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Logged in Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                DialogProfile dialog = new DialogProfile();
                                dialog.show(requireFragmentManager(), "DialogProfile");
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error ! " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
    
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add the `int` at the `class` as increment. You can do something like this.

At the class.

```
public static String surname;
public static String email;
private int counter = 1; //Add this one.
```

And then at the method `onComplete()`

```
  @Override
  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
  if (task.isSuccessful()) {
     Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Logged in Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     if (counter >1){
        //DialogFragment2
     }else{
        DialogProfile dialog = new DialogProfile();
        dialog.show(requireFragmentManager(), "DialogProfile");
        counter++; //increment
     }
  } else {
     Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error ! " + task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
  }
```